# IronPython: double keyword not recognised?

Tags: python, .net, types, ironpython

In IronPython I can do:

```
Console.WriteLine(int.MaxValue)
```

where *int* is not a variable but rather System.Int32. I get back:

```
Max of int: 2137483647
```

Yet if I try something similar for *double* (System.Double), I get:

```
NameError: name 'double' is not defined.
```

Similary for *char* (System.Char). How come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Mapping between Python builtin types and .NET types](http://ironpython.net/documentation/dotnet/dotnet.html#mapping-between-python-builtin-types-and-net-types)

`int` is not a keyword, it is a builtin type in Python, and IronPython implements it using `System.Int32`. Similarly `float` is implemented using `System.Double`.

`double` and `char` are not builtin types in Python.